# How to size the WPF Grid panel this way?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, grid-layout

I have this pretty simple window with a Grid containing two columns, a TextBlock and a TextBox.

[image]

What I need  it to set the column 0 to automatically size to its content and to have column 1 (content) to be 4 times the size of the column 0.

How can I do that. I will create a Grid descendant if this is the solution because I really need this feature.

**Edit:** more explanations. The content of the column 0 won't change at runtime so the size of the column 0 or column 1 must not change on runtime. The grid will be the child of a window configured with `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` so no extra space must exist.

**Answer to Dmitry**: I tried what you say with the following code and it is not working at all:

```
<Window x:Class="UnderstandSizing.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" 
SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" >
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".75*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="THIS IS THE LABEL:" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="content" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**Last Edit: Why the hell do I (or anyone) need this?**

One of the nice things of WPF is its hability to work without fixed sizes right? If you are impaired and you have a bigger font size everything will look fine. If you translate your UI to another language that needs x2 size everything will look fine. If you have different PPI settings everything will look fine.

But what I don't want to see is screens changing its size at runtime because users are not used to this. That's why I want to set the size of the entry fields to a multiple of a know field. If I let the label cell to re size to what it needs and then I set the content cell to a multiplier of the label I will get the benefits of autosizing with the behaviour that users expect of having fixed size screens (unless they change it resizing it).

Comment: Do you want the grid's outer size to expand when the size of the column 1 content increases? Or do you have a given space inside which the grid must stay? Or is the width of column 1 constant and known at compile-time?

Comment: One question: If you want column 1 four times the size of column 0, what happens with the remaining space? Or, what do you want if width of column 0 + 4 times width of column 0 exceedes the available space?

Comment: Did you try using percentages - http://www.tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=36

Comment: @Dmitry `0.2*` and `0.8*` is the same as `*` and `4*`, while the latter is closer to what SoMoS is looking for.

Comment: @All: added more explanations to help you understand the issue. Thanks to all.

Comment: @SoMoS see my updated answer. It does work, you've to consider the child controls behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use bindings on grid columns:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColmunDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="firstCol"/>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=firstCol, Converter={StaticResource MultiplyConverter}, ConverterParameter=4}" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Then the converter:

```
public class MultiplyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double originalValue;
        double multiplier;
        if (value != null && parameter != null && 
            double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out originalValue) &&
            double.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out multiplier)) //Can be lots of things: sentinel object, NaN (not a number)...
        {
            return originalValue * multiplier;
        }
        else return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You could write an attached property for grid columns also.

Comment: Looks as doable. Can you explain a bit the attached property thing? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: You can simply check `if(value is double)`, then it can't be null and doesn't need to be parsed. Also, have a look at [Binding.DoNothing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.donothing.aspx). +1 for using ConverterParameter for flexibility...

Comment: Depends on how advanced you are in WPF because it would be a bit tricky to implement. I can think of several ways but I guess you should read on attached properties (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx). It allows you to add a property to an UIElement, and manipulate its values using callbacks.

Comment: @Martin good point on the Binding.DoNothing . I'm not so sure about the `value is double` thing as they are in fact strings.

Comment: @Baboon: Maybe for ColumnDefinitions. A width of an object is a double. I debugged it and looked at `value.GetType().ToString()`. Result: `System.Double`.

Comment: It's not working. When I use your code the value is an object of type GridLenght set to Auto not a double. You must use ActualWidth right?

Comment: Nope, ActualWidth is returning 0 at runtime (even when it works at the Visualstudio editor ... weird). ANy hints?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from: http://www.tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=36

the idea is to use:

Update 2 - full XAML posted (mind the behavior of your grid's children):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width=".75*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Background="Yellow" Grid.Column="0">
                <TextBlock  Text="THIS IS THE LABEL:" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid Background="Blue" Grid.Column="1">
                <TextBox Background="Transparent" Text="content" />
            </Grid>

        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I've just checked it and it worked.

Update: Simply put - there's no out of the box way for doing this in WPF. Depending on your circumstanes you'll have to come up with some sort of a trick to get your grid working.

Another problem is - in general WPF layouts are designed to be protective, i.e. if your grid's child cannot be shrinked down - normally your layout logic should accomodate for it, typically by suspending some layout rules.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all, I'm afraid. How do you change the width of the Grid when the size of the column 0 content changes?

Comment: The question is: Did *you* try it? Your grid will always expand over the whole width and column 0 will usually not have the exact width of its content.

Comment: No it's not, Martin. Put two buttons into the grid and try it.

Comment: That's because the buttons autosize to the size of the grid. Set the first button's width to '20' and see if the second column's width will be '60' automatically.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

If the sizes are known at compile time, wouldn't it be easier to set the widths manually?

---

You could use a BindingConverter for that, I'd go with separate items in a horizontal StackPanel (look that the StackPanel's width is big enough for your contents):

Here's the cleaned code.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<!-- define xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourAppNamespace" -->
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <local:WidthConverter x:Key="wc" />
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Grid Background="Gray" x:Name="col1">
        <TextBlock Text="blub"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Background="Orange" Width="{Binding ElementName=col1, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=wc}}">
        <Label Content="bla"></Label>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public class WidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is double))
        {
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }
        return ((double)value) * 4.0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work for entire columns, it's just between the Label and the TextBlock.

Comment: I don't know a better way for creating choppy irresponsive UI than the one you posted. do you use it in your projects?

Comment: @Baboon: Ok, changed it, now the grids depend on each other.

Comment: @Dmitry: The StackPanel assures that the two grids are aligned to the left and only occupy the space they need.

Comment: The sizes are not known at compile time, are only known at the very beginning of the execution. Read my last edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are trying to layout the label (textblock) and the corresponding entry field for it. As an indicator, you should first see the [`Beth Massi's` `Windows Client` video](http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=41987) on simple data entry form which is on developing a `data entry` form but laying out is also demonstrated very well.

Particularly observe how she lays out the controls on the WPF Window using the designer, properties window and `XAML`, and then I think you should not have a need for the first column to be of `Auto` size and second column of `4*` first column.

**EDIT:** As per update in question, I am posting a possible solution as below:

1. XAML file code (Notice the `SizeToContent` usage in `Window` and that the binding is to `ActualWidth` property for `Textbox` control):

   ```xml
   <Window x:Class="GridTest.MainWindow"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GridTest"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       Title="MainWindow"
       d:DesignHeight="350"
       d:DesignWidth="525"
       SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
       mc:Ignorable="d">
   <Grid>
       <Grid.Resources>
           <local:FourWidthConverter x:Key="FourWidthConv" />
       </Grid.Resources>
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <TextBlock Name="tb"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  Text="Auto Text, change at design time to see changes in Width" />
       <TextBox Name="tx"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Width="{Binding ElementName=tb,
                                Path=ActualWidth,
                                Converter={StaticResource FourWidthConv}}"
                Text="4 * col 1 width displaying Text in SizetoContentWindow" />
   </Grid>
   </Window>
   ```
2. `.Xaml.cs` file code (Notice the converter here):

   ```
   using System.Windows;
   using System.Windows.Data;

   namespace GridTest
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
       /// </summary>
       public partial class MainWindow : Window
       {
           public MainWindow()
           {
               InitializeComponent();
           }
       }

       public class FourWidthConverter : IValueConverter
       {
           public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
           {
               return 4 * (double)value;
           }

           public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
           {
               throw new System.NotImplementedException();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: read my edit to understand why me or anyone could need this feature.

Comment: @SoMoS I have edited my answer and posted a possible solution, please see the EDIT..

Comment: @SoMoS Probably you would need to implement this code inside a User Control rather than a Window for reusing this kind of feature.